Image responsiveness using css
What CSS properties should I use to ensure images scale appropriately on mobile devices?
I know about <picture> tag with source attribute to use different images at different screen width but other than that is there any way i can make images fully responsive through css?
<picture>
                    <source media="(min-width:769px)" srcset="images/DesktopMode.png">
                    <source media="(min-width:321px)" srcset="images/DesktopTabletMode.jpg">
                    <source media="(min-width:100px)" srcset="images/DesktopPhonemode.png">
                    <img id="decorativeimage" src="images/DesktopMode.png" alt="a  cartoon image of a web developer">
                </picture>

here is my code
I want to make the image responsive using css not through the  picture tag

When you say "responsive", what are you after? There's a difference between scaling an image and serving a different version of an image based on the device (the latter is what your picture is doing now).
